# Accesing a Data Access Layer from an MVC based GUI

Tags: java, javafx

**Situation:** I have an MVC Application coded using JavaFX.
I have another application coding a Data Access Layer.
Basically, I need to access to the DAL from the MVC App to display data.

**Goal:** I would like to have a Data Access Layer that is independant of the "View" project. ie, I want to be able to use the same DAL to display data on a GUI as much as on a JSP (for example).

**Problem:** If both apps were in the same App as packages, I would be able to use Model Classes in my DAL to populate object lists from the Database.

However, as I have two different Apps (let's say the DAL was already there, coded by another team), I cannot reference the Model Classes in the DAL, as I am already referencing the DAL Project in the MVC Project (this would result in circular reference).

in short, references are like this : **DAL =>  MVC**
But I need to use the Model in the DAL to populate classes from database requests.

**Solutions Considered:** 
I thought of using the **DAO Design Pattern**, but shouldnt that be in the DAL Project and not in the MVC Project ? Which doest not really solve the issue.

I feel there is a need to have Specific Business Classes, that should then be converted to Model Classes in the MVC Project (which sounds a bit shaky and redundant IMHO)

PS : The Model layer from JavaFX is constraining (using fields like StringPropery, IntegerProperty) otherwhise I would isolate it as an independent project (maybe, just an option...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go like this. Create a dumb DTO layer in DAL project and have your DAL project to get data from Database, populate the DTP and return the DTO. MVC project can still have DAL project as your dependency.

In the MVC Service class, call the DAL code, get the DTO object and map to the JavaFX Model object. By doing so, any app consuming the DAL project will get a uniform a DTO as reponse, and the consumer can map it to their own model as needed.

Note: Typically, in Spring world, models are pretty dumb with just getters and setters and I would make them part of DAL project itself. I thought of moving them to DAL itself. Since model objects are specific to JavaFX, i wouldn't think of moving them to DAL.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this confirms exactly what I wat thinking. 
TBH I dislike the Mapping step, but in this case I think I have to do with.